# How to develop app that support multiple device using phonegap

Tags: cordova

I want to create Html, Css and javascript based single app that must have to run on all the mobile device without code changing. Can it be possible using phonegap. If yes then how can be done?

Thanks for helping me.

Comment: You could look at [Bd](https://build.phonegap.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Yes! You can use phonegap or cordova for this.

Just keep in mind for any -specific OS targeted- plugins.

Regards,
Vangelis